Solving PDE with conditions on the diagonal
I'm trying to solve
$$
\gamma_{uv}=-\sin\gamma,
$$
with $\gamma(u,u)=f_1(u)$ and $\gamma_n(u,u)=f_2(u)$, being $f_1$ and $f_2$ some given functions and $n$ means the derivative normal to the line $u=v$. We take $u,v$ in some rectangle $[u_1,u_2]\times[v_1,v_2]$.
This can be done rotating to $\xi=u+v$ and $\eta=u-v$, where the problem is simply
  \[Xi]lim = {-2, 2}; 
  \[Eta]lim = {-2, 2}; 
  NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][\[Gamma]][\[Xi], \[Eta]] - Derivative[0, 2][\[Gamma]][\[Xi], \[Eta]] == -Sin[\[Gamma][\[Xi], \[Eta]]], \[Gamma][\[Xi], 0] == \[Xi] + 1, Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][\[Xi], 0] == \[Xi]}, \[Gamma], {\[Xi], \[Xi]lim[[1]], \[Xi]lim[[2]]}, {\[Eta], \[Xi]lim[[1]], \[Eta]lim[[2]]}] 

However this rotation is inconvenient for my purposes, and I would like to solve the problem in the $u,v$ coordinates directly. But apparently NDSolve does not recognize the condition when I put \[Gamma][u,u]=f1[u] and the derivative?

Perhaps you succeed if you include the line u=v as a boundary in the elementmesh?

@UlrichNeumann Theoretically speaking there is no need for the diagonal to be the boundary. One can grow the solution into either side of the line until a singularity is hit.

My hint concerns FEM solution. DirichletConditions have to be set on the boundary

Where are   f1[u],f2[u] defined?

@UlrichNeumann we can take them to be $1+u$ and $1+u \sin(u)$ respectively, but it really doesn't matter as long are they are smooth functions.

Actually, we have two normal vectors to the line $u=v$. From your example follows that you take one of them. Should we take same or different? Also, please note that only Dirichlet condition on diagonal $u=v$ could be fine to solve the problem.

@AlexTrounev In principle anyone, but for definiteness let's say we take the $n$ so that $n\cdot u$ is negative (that is, 'to the left'). Why is it so that only Dirichlet works ? It's all well posed with this Cauchy conditions (meaning value for the function plus normal derivative to the curve).

@DanielCastro Ok, I have FDM solution to your problem Is it you are looking for? :)

@AlexTrounev I am looking for a solution in any format. Any help is acknowledged of course.

@DanielCastro I'm unsure about your \[Gamma][\[Xi], \[Eta]]-solution. I would expect boundary conditions \[Gamma][\[Xi], 0] == \[Xi]/2 + 1, -2 Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][\[Xi]/2, 0] == 1 + \[Xi]/2 Sin[\[Xi]/2]

@UlrichNeumann As per the mathematics of the problems, they are two arbitrary smooth functions. One can whatever and in the vicinity of the initial line the solution should exist. True, for most choices a singularity appears very close to the line and one loses the solution, but that's another story.

@DanielCastro I just wanted to know if the formulation of the transformed system t\[Gamma][\[Xi], \[Eta]]-solution is correc

This problem can be solved with FDM using modified code from my answer here
XYgrid[dom_List, pts_List] := 
  MapThread[
   N@Range[Sequence @@ #1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/#2] &, {dom, 
    pts - 1}];
BoundaryIndex[xgridlen_, ygridlen_] := 
  Module[{tmp, left, right, bot, top, dia, dia1}, 
   tmp = Table[(n - 1) ygridlen + Range[1, ygridlen], {n, 1, 
      xgridlen}]; {left, right} = tmp[[{1, -1}]]; {bot, top} = 
    Transpose[{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ tmp]; dia = Diagonal[tmp]; 
   dia1 = Diagonal[tmp, 1]; {top, right[[2 ;; -2]], bot, 
    left[[2 ;; -2]], dia, dia1}];
FDMat[deriv_, xygrid_, difforder_] := 
 Map[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, xygrid, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"] &, deriv]
{domain, pts, difforder} = {{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {121, 121}, 4};
xygrid = XYgrid[domain, pts]; {nx, ny} = 
 Map[Length, xygrid]; {top, right, bot, left, d, d1} = 
 BoundaryIndex[nx, ny]; {dx, dy, dx2, dy2, dxy} = 
 FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}}, xygrid, 
  difforder]; boundaries = Join[top, right, bot, left]; sgrid = 
 Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ xygrid], 1];
    gamma = Array[gg, nx ny];

Please note, that we define diagonal and super diagonal to implement boundary conditions. See these points in red and green consequently
ListPlot[{sgrid, sgrid[[d]], sgrid[[d1]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, AspectRatio -> 1]


Numerical solution
f1[x_] := 1 + x; f2[x_] := 1 + x Sin[x];
eq = dxy . gamma + Sin[gamma]; 
eq[[d]] = gamma[[d]] - f1[sgrid[[d]][[All, 1]]]; 
eq[[d1]] = {-1, 1} . {(dx . gamma)[[d1]], (dy . gamma)[[d1]]}/
   Sqrt[2] - f2[sgrid[[d1]][[All, 1]]];

sol = FindRoot[Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, nx ny}], 
   Table[{gamma[[i]], .1}, {i, nx ny}]];

{g} = Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
   Partition[gamma /. sol, Length[sgrid]]];

Visualization of function and error for bc implementation
{ContourPlot[g[u, v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "\[Gamma]"], 
 Plot[g[x, x] - f1[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "\[Gamma](u,u)-f1(u)"], 
 Plot[({-1, 1} . {Derivative[1, 0][g][x, x], 
       Derivative[0, 1][g][x, x]}/Sqrt[2] - f2[x]), {x, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Gamma]\), \(n\)]\)(u,u)-f2(u)"]}


As we can see the error for Dirichlet condition is about 10^-8, while for Neumann value we have error of about 0.03. It is why we need bc for second normal as well.

Also, to change the domain to some arbitrary $[u_1,u_2]\times[v_1,v_2]$, we just do it in the value of domain ?

Thank you. I have a question, to what extent is this method better that raw NDSolve ? When change even slightly the conditions the errors goes quite high, of the order of 1.

@DanielCastro Yes, we set domain in domain, but we can't use arbitrary domain since we define line u=v as diagonal of domain for simplification - see Figure 1 and definition for d and d1.

@AlexTrounev Did you compare your solution with QP's solution \[Gamma][\[Xi], \[Eta]]?

@UlrichNeumann What is the reason to compare OP's solution with my solution while they defined on different domain? :) On the other hand, we can solve it with FEM as you suggested.

@AlexTrounev Transforming back QP's solution gamma[u+v,u-v] should match your FDM solution. FEM solution is  still  in progress...

@UlrichNeumann You are not right. We should simultaneously transform domain $-2\le \xi\le 2, -2\le \eta \le 2 $. Also, Daniel used different bc and we have message to his solution NDSolveValue::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable \[Xi]. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.
